# Update Table with DTOList

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables. One of them is Customers which is in the database, the other one is ChangedCustomers, which comes from the user. I make some operations on ChangedCustomers table before sending the database so I use ChangedCustomersDTO. After these operations, I can not update the database.

```
 public async Task<int> UpdateCustomers (IENumerable<ChangedCustomersDTO> changedCustomers
{
  foreach(var item in changedCustomers)
  {
    var customer=_context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == item.CustomerId);
    
    if(customer != null)
    {
      customer.Id=item.Id;
      customer.Name=item.Name;
      customer.Address=item.Address;
    }
    else 
    {
      _context.Customers.Add(new Models.Customers()
     {
      customer.Id=new Guid();
      customer.Name=item.Name;
      customer.Address=item.Address;
     }
    }
  }
return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

All the data I have at the moment will be updated customers. They entered the `if(customer !=null)`  but the method returns 0 and  is not updated.

After comments I edit my code, but again returns zero.

```
public async Task<int> UpdateCustomers (IENumerable<ChangedCustomersDTO> changedCustomers
{
  foreach(var item in changedCustomers)
  {
    var customer=_context.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == item.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
    
    if(customer != null)
    {
      customer.Name=item.Name;
      customer.Address=item.Address;
    }
    else 
    {
      _context.Customers.Add(new Models.Customers()
     {
      customer.Id=new Guid();
      customer.Name=item.Name;
      customer.Address=item.Address;
     }
    }
  }
return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: It looks like your mistake is setting the Customer.Id equal to the item.Id. There probably is no customer with that id and this operation is a modify, not an Add. Why do you even need to reset the id?

Comment: I compare it. I have 4 customers in changedCustomer list ,  Customer.Id and item.Id values are equal. You can say "why you are update the Id, it couldn't change". When I try to remove customer.Id=item.Id, it throws an error about primary key.

Comment: So, item.CustomerId and item.Id are the same value? You have selected the customer based on item.CustomerId but you are setting it to item.id.

Comment: How can I fix this, I am confused. Now I am tried without  customer.Id=item.Id; . Again returns zero.

Comment: You need to straighten out if you are setting the id or the CustomerId. You almost never change a primary key.

Comment: This line is wrong : var customer=_context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == item.CustomerId);  Try : var customer=_context.Customers(x => x.CustomerId == item.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng I try this, but again returns zero. I get the actual values in customer in if block but they don't update db.

Comment: Do you have more than one row for each customer? Using FirstOrDefault() will only update one row in the database.

Comment: No, I have one row for each customer. After the operations in if() for customer, var customer is OK. I got the row which will update. But it doesn't update in db

Comment: This post needs  more details and clarity. The posted code can't be  compilled.

Answer (score 0):

you have several bugs in your code. try this:

```
 var customer=_context.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault(); 

if(customer != null)
    {
      customer.Name=item.Name;
      customer.Address=item.Address;
     _context.Entry(customer).State=EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else 
    {
      _context.Customers.Add(new Models.Customers 
     {
     Id=new Guid(),
      Name=item.Name,
      Address=item.Address
     }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your Customer and ChangedCustomersDTO, pls