# Updating multiple rows in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to update multiple rows. My method is running, the values as should be. But data does not update and the method is returning zero. My Ids are guid, so customer value every time gets one row.

```
public async Task<int> UpdateCustomers (IENumerable<ChangedCustomersDTO> changedCustomers)
{
    foreach(var item in changedCustomers)
    {
        var customer = _context.Customers
                               .Where(x => x.CustomerId == item.CustomerId)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
     
        customer.Name = item.Name;
        customer.Address=item.Address;
    }

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Is there something I missed? I search this issue but always reach this method and it is not working for me? Is there anywhere should I change?

Comment: You query based on CustomerId and change the value of Id. Which property is mapped as an Id in EF?

Comment: Actually it is not changed when I update the values. Only name and address changes.  I am editing the mehtod

Comment: Your code looks good now (save for the NRE when customer is null), clearly the problem must come from some error in your entity class or mapping configuration.

Comment: This isn't real code because `FirstOrDefault;` would not compile.

Comment: Are you really stuck with this? Since I do not have permission to copy and propagate the actual code, I wrote it with similar variables. @tymtam

Comment: The problem is that if something that suppose to work doesn't work is hard to analyse using example code, because the example code may not show the reason the original code doesn't work.

Comment: I guess you could not work it out on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67333324/update-table-with-dtolist#comment119015663_67333324)?  At this point I suggest you [trace the SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) so you can see what it is trying to do.

Comment: As a side note, the advice given to you on the previous question regarding how to use FirstOrDefault is wrong, you don't need both `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`, you could just put your predicate in `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Table with DTOList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67333324/update-table-with-dtolist)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to announce the change mode of the database to
entity-framework.

for add data to db

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var book = new Book { Name = "book 1" };
    context.Books.Add(book);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

or you can set `EntityState.Modified`

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var book = new Book { Name = "book 1" };
    context.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Added;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

for update data

```
public async Task<int> UpdateCustomers (IENumerable<ChangedCustomersDTO> changedCustomers)
{
    foreach(var item in changedCustomers)
    {
        var customer = _context.Customers
                               .Where(x => x.CustomerId == item.CustomerId)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
     
        customer.Name = item.Name;
        customer.Address=item.Address;
        context.Entry(customer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If you want to update multiple records with similar values, you can use .ForEach

```
public async Task<int> UpdateCustomers (IEnumerable<ChangedCustomersDTO> changedCustomers)
{
   changedCustomers.ToList().ForEach(a =>
   {
       a.Name = "value1";
       a.Address = "value2";
   });
   return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```